# How to get all values from OptionMenus with one button

Tags: python, tkinter

How to get all values ​​from OptionMenus with one button. I would like to get a similar effect as in the WWW form.
I was able to collect values ​​in a very unprofessional way (for each individual).It hurts my eyes :D

```
def funcUser(value):
    add_item(listaUser, value)

mies = OptionMenu(root, value, *list,command=func)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get all values"? An OptionMenu is designed to provide a single value.

Comment: @BryanOakley I meant selected options from all OptionMenus. 
In my program, I have 5 of them.With various options to choose

Answer (score 0):

If you add their `StringVar`s to a list, you can do it like in this example:

```
    from tkinter import *
    master = Tk()
    variables=[StringVar(master) for i in range(3)]
    for i in variables:
        i.set('one')
        option = OptionMenu(master, i, "one", "two", "three", "four")
        option.pack() 
    def ok():
        contents=[i.get() for i in variables]
        print("the values are", contents)
    button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
    button.pack()

    mainloop()
```